# unable access controller scope from custom directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I a trying to access controller scope in my directive but can't access. I created a directive 'dynamicElement' to create new HTML element and its working fine, but in my directive i am not able to access my controller scope.

My Code: **Controller**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, SurveyQuest, $state, $stateParams, $sce) {

var QuestData = SurveyQuest.all();
if($state.params.qid == ''){

    var questionOrder = 1;
}else{

    var questionOrder = $state.params.qid;
}
//console.log(QuestData.data[paramQid]);
//console.log(QuestData);
//console.log(QuestData.data.length);
var paramQid;

angular.forEach(QuestData.data, function(value, key) {
    if(value.question_order == questionOrder){

        paramQid = key;
    }
    //console.log(value.question_order+' '+key);
});
console.log(paramQid);
console.log(QuestData.data);
$scope.question = $sce.trustAsHtml(QuestData.data[paramQid].question_text);
$scope.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(QuestData.data[paramQid].question_desc);
switch(QuestData.data[paramQid].question_type){

    case'radio':
    var radioLength = QuestData.data[paramQid].answers.length;

    var finalAnswers = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++){

        finalAnswers+= '<label><input type="radio" ng-click="clickMe($event)"  data-id="'+QuestData.data[paramQid].answers[i].option_next+'" name="'+QuestData.data[paramQid].question_id+'" value="'+QuestData.data[paramQid].answers[i].option_value+'" /> '+QuestData.data[paramQid].answers[i].option_text+'</label>';
    }
    $scope.htmlString = finalAnswers;
    break;
    .............
    $scope.next = function(qid){
        console.log(qid);
        $state.go('tab.dash',{'qid':qid});
    }
```

**View Code:**

```
<dynamic-element message='htmlString' ng-bind-html="ans"></dynamic-element>
<div class="buttons" style="text-align:center; margin-top:10%;">
  <button class="button button-positive">
    &nbsp; Prev &nbsp;
  </button>
  <button class="button button-assertive" >
   &nbsp; Stop &nbsp;
  </button>
  <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="next({{qid}})">
   &nbsp; Next &nbsp;
  </button>
</div>
```

**Directive Code:**

```
.directive('dynamicElement', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        message: "="
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var template = $compile(scope.message)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(template);               
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.clickMe = function(item){

            $scope.qid = item.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id"); //NOT WORKING

            console.log(item.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id"));
       };
    }]
  }
  }])
```

Kindly suggest me..Thanks

Comment: I think the correct way to do this is to use transclude , see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: if you can provide a jsfiddle demo link, i can help to debug

Comment: [JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rahul841990/jeh2k8yz/43/)

Comment: @BowenLi did you find any solution?

Comment: please click the jsfiddle link in my answer